# Why does Python respond with an error message after the else statement?

Tags: python-3.x, syntax-error

I'm new to Python. I'm thinking about this error for 2 days now. I feel the answer is simple but it eludes me still. My code is for translating time periods into seconds:

```
#input
input_time_from_user = input('Enter time in years, months, weeks, days, hours:')
input_time = input_time_from_user.split()[0]
input_category = input_time_from_user.split()[1]
ConvertedInteger_input_time = int(input_time)

#processing
if input_category == 'years':
     time_in_seconds = ConvertedInteger_input_time*365*24*60*60
elif input_category == 'months':
     time_in_seconds = ConvertedInteger_input_time*30.42*24*60*60
elif input_category == 'days':
     time_in_seconds = ConvertedInteger_input_time*24*60*60
else input_category == 'hours':
     time_in_seconds = ConvertedInteger_input_time*60

print('The converted time of {} in seconds is {}'.format(input_time_from_user, time_in_seconds))
```

In this current form, I get an error statement:

```
File "<ipython-input-21-91bf6c885d46>", line 16
else input_category == 'hours':
                   ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

If I disable the else statement, it runs ok. What could've gone wrong ? Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your last statement is an else, but you provided a condition, it should be an elif

The else statement is to use without any condition, it basically means "everything else".

For reference:
https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_conditions.asp

```
if input_category == 'years':
     time_in_seconds = ConvertedInteger_input_time*365*24*60*60
elif input_category == 'months':
     time_in_seconds = ConvertedInteger_input_time*30.42*24*60*60
elif input_category == 'days':
     time_in_seconds = ConvertedInteger_input_time*24*60*60
elif input_category == 'hours':
     time_in_seconds = ConvertedInteger_input_time*60
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html?highlight=else#if-statements)

```
>>> x = int(input("Please enter an integer: "))
Please enter an integer: 42
>>> if x < 0:
...     x = 0
...     print('Negative changed to zero')
... elif x == 0:
...     print('Zero')
... elif x == 1:
...     print('Single')
... else:
...     print('More')
...
```

An else statement does not take a logical test.

To fix your code:

```
#input
input_time_from_user = input('Enter time in years, months, weeks, days, hours:')
input_time = input_time_from_user.split()[0]
input_category = input_time_from_user.split()[1]
ConvertedInteger_input_time = int(input_time)

#processing
if input_category == 'years':
     time_in_seconds = ConvertedInteger_input_time*365*24*60*60
elif input_category == 'months':
     time_in_seconds = ConvertedInteger_input_time*30.42*24*60*60
elif input_category == 'days':
     time_in_seconds = ConvertedInteger_input_time*24*60*60
elif input_category == 'hours':
     time_in_seconds = ConvertedInteger_input_time*60
else:
     pass
     #put a fallthrough condition here, if needed. 

print('The converted time of {} in seconds is {}'.format(input_time_from_user, time_in_seconds))
```

If you need an else condition, put that at the end where I have `pass`.